# cpp language parser in ruby

Tags: c++, ruby

I have a project written in C++. Some Struct in the code takes spec info, so I need to fetch and parse them. I wrote with Ruby a script that keeps track of pre-process (ex `#if`, `#ifdef`) status and class/struct/method border, while others treat as text so I scan the keywords, but it is not smart. To parse C++ code, I installed [a C++ parser in Ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/lpt/), but it has bugs and is old. Is there suggestion for any Ruby gem to parse C++ code? Or, is there any smart solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing C++ is very, very, very much not an easy task. It is one of the most syntactically complicated languages in existence. Instead of trying to parse the C++, a better approach would be to just have your Ruby output the struct definition according to the fetched spec info.

If you must parse C++, your best bet is probably to try to leverage [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html). AFAIK there aren't currently any Ruby bindings yet, but, I mean, parsing C++ isn't something you can expect every language to have a library for. It's a really involved and extremely niche task. That's the most accessible way to do it.

Comment: Here is a ruby binding to ``clang`` https://github.com/ioquatix/ffi-clang